# Script to update domain computer LastLogonDate?

Tags: windows, windows-7, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

So I've poked around looking for something like this for a while now, but can't seem to find anything anywhere.  In our environment we have a script that disables computers after the last seen AD property on a computer is beyond 15 days.  Since we are a mostly laptop environment and people frequently are not connected to the network when they login, the computers once they lock/unlock when eventually do get connected to the domain gets a trust relationship issue because obviously the computer is disabled in AD.

Has anyone seen a script that can run on the local computer that updates the LastLogonDate property in AD of the computer while the user is logged in?  I was thinking of just pushing out a scheduled task to all computers that does this every 15 minutes if its even possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible without knowing the computer account password which you don't know. Off the top of my head you could write a very tiny app that runs once an hour or even less (don't need to go overboard) that writes a heartbeat to `extensionAttribute1` or another field in AD that is not used and filter on that instead.

Comment: Thanks @Ashigore I assumed it wasn't possible to do but just wanted confirmation.  Cheers.